# Secend loop in sudoku, generate solver

Tags: c#

This is my first question here, so sorry for any mistake.

How to do second loop to generate unique rows?

Every time when i add second loop to find unique solution program hangup...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] tab = new int[9, 9];

        Random r = new Random();

        List<int> temp = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {                    
                while (true)
                {
                    bool uniq = true;

                    int randomNumber = r.Next(0, 9);

                    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
                    {                       
                        if (randomNumber==tab[z,j])
                        {
                            uniq = false;   
                        }
                     }                    
                     if (uniq == false)
                     {
                        continue;
                     }
                     tab[i, j] = randomNumber;

                     temp.Remove(randomNumber);
                     break;
                }
```

Comment: "program hangup"  - what does that mean?

Comment: So. Many. Loops.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to generate table with unique numbers in every row and columns. In my program i get unique columns numbers but i have no idea how to do that the same with numbers in rows...

Comment: When i tried add any other loop with all different ways, always my program frozen.

Comment: What's the point of the `break` at the end of the `while (true)`?

Comment: Don't search for unique numbers in a loop like that. Start with a list of integers, randomly sort it, and then remove one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Random r = new Random();

void Main()
{
    int[,] tab = new int[9, 9];

    List<int> digits = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        List<int> temp = digits.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToList();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            tab[i, j] = temp[j];
        }
    }
}
```